# package nodejs project into an executable

Tags: javascript, package, puppeteer, exe

I want to package my nodejs project.
But when i type `pkg package.json` on my cmd, i receive this error message > pkg@5.8.0

> Warning Cannot include directory %1 into executable.
> The directory must be distributed with executable as %2.
> %1: codeSource\node_modules\puppeteer.local-chromium
> %2: path-to-executable/puppeteer`

As i understood,that's mean that i have to pass the puppeteer dependencies on the same folder of the executable file.

Ive tried it but it still doesnt work.

Here is my package.json : [image: package.json]

What do I do wrong ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It says that the first argument should be a directory, but you tried to pass a file

Comment: I dont get it, wich argument are you talking about ?

Comment: To the `pkg` script

Comment: So the syntax pkg `package.json` doesnt exist ?

Comment: I don't see it in the examples

Comment: I do on this https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg?activeTab=readme its written `Just be sure to call pkg package.json or pkg . to make use of package.json configuration` and even when i type `pkg .`it still doesnt work.

Comment: Please post files [as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Thanks.